# Matlab timeout error when connecting to FTP server

Tags: matlab, networking, ftp

I'm using a MATLAB code that connects to an ftp server and reads the directory of all the existing files there. my access to this FTP server is restricted and I only have a view access to this server.
It used to work perfectly but recently it gives this error:

```
Error using ftp/dir (line 64)
Java exception occurred:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:489)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listNames(FTPClient.java:1950)
```

Is there anything I can do in my MATLAB code to resolve this issue since I don't have access to the FTP server?

I could only check out the speed of the FTP server by opening it. It opens almost with very little delay.

Comment: If the code used to work, and you didn’t change it, then there is no reason to think the code is broken. A network connection timing out is something you should ask your network administrator about.